# make[1]: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop

Tags: swift, baresip

try to implement an barsip-iOS. am facing some error

> make[1]: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop.

and am i install

- libre library in my system
- librem library in my system
- openssl library in my system

what i do next?

how to use baresip library in ios.